# Young adult/teen fiction about a kid that is somehow transported into various numbered worlds

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read this book in the early 2000s. I remember the kid being in a field of wildflowers with a white gazebo that either faded into the air or into water. They were then transported to different numbered worlds. In one of the worlds she meets a man that wears a bunch of hats. I want to say he looked like a devil, but I’m not entirely sure..

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  How are the worlds numbered?  Is it like the homeworld is 1, next world is 2, or do they all have multidigit numbers?  Also, you mean "wears a bunch of hats" literally, or [figuratively](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wear%20many%20hats)?  Does the kid try to get home?  Does she succeed?